# Can I send an ACK response to a successfully received SYNACK using BSD raw sockets?

Tags: tcp, raw-sockets

My code tries to manually establish a `TCP` handshaking, and then, it sends a data segment requesting a resource via `HTTP GET`.

I'm using raw sockets to craft the headers and send the packets, and libpcap in order to check for the received packet headers.

The `SYN` is successfully sent to the receiver, who then replies me with a `SYNACK`. At this point so far it works, but when I receive that `SYNACK`, I try to `ACK` it, and then send `HTTP GET` next, which doesn't look to work. I can see the headers are ok in wireshark.

So my questions are: can i `ACK` the `SYNACK` via raw sockets just as I receive it using the same socket I used to send the `SYN`? And is there any required `OPTIONS` to go along with the headers in order to accomplish that?

I'm ACKing that `SYNACK`, and just after that I send a segment with `ACK` and `PSH` flags set in order to request a resource via `HTTP`. I can see them both on wireshark, but I don't get a response from the server.

Comment: Update your question with the contents of the `SYN`, `SYNACK` and `ACK` TCP headers as shown in Wireshark.

Comment: There are lots things that can go wrong. I will suggest to compare packet capture on both client side and server side. Lists of things that can go wrong include wrong ack number (it should be syn-ack seq number +1) checksum of tcp segment, checksum of ip packet, also there could be checksum offloading on your nic card which might be changing checksums.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't `ACK` using raw sockets, however your OS's kernel stack will also see the received `SYNACK` which it isn't expecting and send a `RST`. Are you doing anything to prevent that from happening? Otherwise, maybe you aren't sending the right SEQ/ACK numbers.

Comment: Yes, I prevented the kernel from doing this by setting a rule on iptables.